# Any way to query either ALL Facebook Pages or the TOP 20% (by likes) using Graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to build my own list of the most 'liked' pages on Facebook.  FB itself appears to do a version of this, at least for each letter of the alphabet.  Each directory page, such as http://www.facebook.com/directory/pages/A lists the top 20 most liked pages starting with that letter.

If I knew the IDs of every FB page then I could easily grab its like count using the graph API, but I don't know of a way to get that initial list.  I'm sure it's huge, and honestly, I really would rather just have the top 20% or so of all pages.  But if I had them all I could do the sorting myself.

I've searched the FB dev forums and looked through their docs but can't find a way.  Queries using FQL don't appear to take wildcards either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FQL, you can search the page table by name.  This doesn't allow wildcard searches though. Using the graph api, you can perform page searches using this url:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&q=test (You would want to future proof this by adding an access_token parameter to the end).  A third option would by to use search engines to search for Facebook pages.  Finally, you could scrape and parse the [Facebook page browser](https://www.facebook.com/pages/browser.php) by using this [url](https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/browser/content.php?country=US&category=10000&start=1050&__a=1).

Comment: So which solution did you use to get the top 20%?  I have a similar issue and i'm not sure which solution is best.